# Logical resolution - Can we resolve two clauses without complementary literals?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I am learning the resolution in propositional logic, and I understand that we can resolve two clauses like $\neg a \lor b$ and $\neg b \lor c$ to produce $\neg a \lor c$. But can we resolve $\neg a \lor b$ and $\neg c \lor d$? If we can, what is the result?

Comment: I don't believe you can use the resolution argument to gain anything useful for this, the two clauses have no common terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You can think about this intuitively.

- Either it is hot out or I am wearing a sweater.
- Either it is not hot out or I am wearing shorts.

From this, you can deduce

- Either I am wearing a sweater or I am wearing shorts.

But imagine there were four different propositions.

- Either it is hot out or I am wearing a sweater.
- Either it is not raining or I am carrying an umbrella.

Clearly, there is nothing we can do to combine and simplify these statements.

Answer (score 1):

To reinforce the other given answer I thought it might be helpful to present a quick symbolic proof for the resolution rule (also equivalently known as hypothetical syllogism) so that you can see the importance of the shared term in the two disjunctions.

---

Given: $\neg a \vee b, \neg b \vee c$ 
Prove: $\neg a \vee c$

$(1) \ \ \neg a \vee b \ \ $ (premise) 
$(2) \ \ \neg b \vee c \ \ $ (premise) 
$(3) \ \ \textbf{Assume } a:$ 
$\ \ \ \ \ \ (4) \ \ b \ \ $ ($1, 3,$ disjunctive syllogism) 
$\ \ \ \ \ \ (5) \ \ c \ \ $ ($2, 4,$ disjunctive syllogism) 
$(6) \ \ \neg a \vee c \ \ $ (introducing an implication and cancelling the assumption at $3$)

---

So you can see between statements $(4)$ and $(5)$ the shared term provides a kind of bridge between the two statements. Without that shared term this argument is simply not possible.